# Flutter show data from mock .json file

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to load data from a mock `recipes.json` file in flutter and I have a structure like this

```
lib
|__mock_data
   |__recipes.json
|__src
   |__models
   |__components
   |__screens
|__app.dart
|__main.dart
```

Now I have created a model which looks like this:

```
class RecipeModel {
  RecipeModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.videoLink,
    required this.author,
    required this.category,
    required this.time,
  });

  String id;
  String name;
  String videoLink;
  String author;
  String category;
  String time;

  factory RecipeModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => RecipeModel(
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
        videoLink:
            json["audioAssetPath"] == null ? null : json["audioAssetPath"],
        author: json["isRemoteUrl"] == null ? null : json["isRemoteUrl"],
        category: json["iconUrl"] == null ? null : json["iconUrl"],
        time: json["vol"] == null ? null : json["vol"].toDouble(),
      );
}
```

In the page where I want to show the data I'm doing this:

```
  Future<List<RecipeModel>> fetchRecipes() async {
    String url =
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boriszv/json/master/random_example.json";
    var response = await http.get(url);  ----------->The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'
    print(response);
    var recipes = <RecipeModel>[];
    var recipesJson = json.decode(response.body);
    for (var index in recipesJson) {
      recipes.add(RecipeModel.fromJson(index));
    }
    throw '';
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchRecipes();
  }
```

I get a error when assigning the URL and also how to load the current `recipe.json` data?

N.B: Are the models written right?Because there might be a shift from `json` to `protobuf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To load a local file, you can put the file in the assets folder.

  ```
  Future<List<RecipeModel>> loadLocalRecipe() async {
  try {
  String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/recipe.json');


  List<dynamic> result = json.decode(response);
      return result.map((n) => RecipeModel.fromJson(n)).toList();
    } catch (e) {
      throw Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
        child: Center(
          child: Text('Convert Error'),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
  ```
- pubspec.yaml

  ```
  flutter:

  assets:
  - assets/receipe.json
  ```
- To get server data, you can use this.

  ```
  Future<List<RecipeModel>> getRecipe() async {
   try {
    final http.Response response = await http.get("https://example.com",
     headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
  );

  // print(response.body);
  List<dynamic> result = json.decode(response.body) as List;
  return result.map((n) => RecipeModel.fromJson(n)).toList();

  } catch (e) {
  throw Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
    child: Center(
      child: Text('Connection Error'),
    ),
    );
   }
  }
  ```